# Calling IronRuby from C# with a delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, ironruby, yield

Is it possible to call an IronRuby method from C# with a delegate as parameter in such a way that `yield` would work?

The following gives me a *wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)* exception.

```
Action<string> action = Console.WriteLine;
var runtime = Ruby.CreateRuntime();
var engine = runtime.GetEngine("rb");
engine.Execute(@"
                 class YieldTest
                   def test
                     yield 'From IronRuby'
                   end
                 end
                ");
object test = engine.Runtime.Globals.GetVariable("YieldTest");
dynamic t = engine.Operations.CreateInstance(test);
t.test(action);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer by [IronRuby core team](http://ironruby.net/About/People) member [Tomáš Matoušek](https://github.com/tmat) on the IronRuby-core list that it's not possible. Yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure Ruby's block is not a c# delegate.
If you pass delegate to Ruby you should invoke it via delegate's Invoke method.
Here is sample code:

```
var rt = Ruby.CreateRuntime();
var eng = rt.GetEngine("rb");
eng.Execute(@"
            class Blocktest
              def test(block)
                block.Invoke('HELLO From IronRuby')
              end
            end
            ");
dynamic ruby = eng.Runtime.Globals;
dynamic t = ruby.Blocktest.@new();
t.test(new Action<string>(Console.WriteLine));
```

Can we convert c# delegate into ruby block... I don't know.

Comment: +1 for showing how to invoke C# delegates from IronRuby. Still curious if there's a way to `yield` C# code from IronRuby.